# Trying to retrieve guild prefix with MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py

I'm trying to setup MongoDB with my discord.py bot. I get it to connect, but I cannot retrieve guild prefixes when I define `command_prefix`.

My current code is:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient("url im not showing")
db = cluster["Cluster0"]
collection = db["Guild Prefixes"]

def get_prefix(bot, message):
    for x in collection.find({"Guild ID": message.guild.id}):
        prefix = x["Prefix"]
    return prefix

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, intents=discord.Intents.all(), case_insensitive=True)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
File "c:\Users\colee\Documents\GitHub\Guard\bot.py", line 11, in get_prefix
    return prefix
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prefix' referenced before assignment
```

My current table looks like:

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `id` returned from `message.guild.id` is of type `int` which can be seen in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.id), but it's stored as a string in MongoDB.

You could convert the ID to a string in the filter like so: `collection.find({"Guild ID": str(message.guild.id)})`

Or you can update the documents to store the ID as an `int` so a conversion isn't necessary.